# ReAsked - Why is manipulating field map schemas inconsistent (ArcGIS)?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, field-mapping

I've got a knotty problem which I am trying to solve in a very methodical and deliberate step by step process, to ensure that non-technical colleagues are able to verify the content every step of the way.

Short version: I'm importing four feature classes from a live environment, to a local file geodatabase, and then reconfiguring the fields and merging them into one. Question at the end.

I'm also new to GIS - using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3 / Python 3.6.8

1. Each of the four feature classes is imported to a local feature class in a local file geodatabase
2. working locally, each local featureclass is overhauled - unwanted fields are dropped, existing fields are renamed, and attributes like string lengths are aligned. I've also used [Josh's code](http://joshwerts.com/blog/2014/04/17/arcpy-reorder-fields/) to re-order the fields
3. Using python, I've created the "ideal" feature class.
4. Then I've tried to populate my ideal featureclass with the contents from all four "fixed" local featureclasses using `arcpy.Append_management(importedFeatureClasses, idealFeatureClass, "TEST")`

The whole script thing works very nicely, but grinds to a halt on the last step - `arcpy.Append_management` with an error `REORDERED_Imported_xxx does not match the schema of target`

The issue seems to be originating from two specific mandatory fields: `shape_length` and `shape_area`.

*Imported_FC*

- labeled as SHAPE_Length and SHAPE_Area
- both are middle of the field list ...

*REORDERED_Imported_FC*

- labelled as Shape_Length and Shape_Area
- both at the end of the field list ....

*Ideal_ FC*

- labelled as Shape_Length and Shape_Area
- 3rd and 4th in the list of fields

So...

1. These are required fields. It seems that because of that they are not able to be modified in any way, I'll have to get creative
2. The labeling of the fields. I'm importing upper case names, but in the process, Josh's code corrects that and makes Sentence Case field labels... so this problem is sorted.

But, my clean, system generated ideal feature class as a target, does still not have the same schema as my REORDERED, imported, feature classes.

3. So, to rework my so called "ideal" feature class, run that too, through Josh's code, then the "unalterable" field order on mandatory fields is in fact altered, and the problem is solved.

**The one Question I am allowed to ask**

I've been led to believe that there are four required fields in this type of feature class. OBJECTID, SHAPE, SHAPE_LENGTH, SHAPE_AREA. They are unalterable in all sorts of ways. But Josh's code using `fieldmaps` **CAN** alter them, both in fixing Sentence_Case, and position in the list of fields.

Why?

Comment: Please don't re-ask. Just edit your original question, also add some code and we should be able to help.

Comment: Well, I did that, but the question remains closed. So what would you like me to do now?

Comment: Wait for it to be re-opened.

Comment: There is a queue that all questions go through to be closed and/or opened.  By editing your original it is put into the queue for a reopen vote, and if the community agrees it will be reopened.  Creating a new question to bypass this process can have a negative effect on this process.

Comment: Well, that may be, but it is not what stackoverflow says. When I edited the question, the banner at the top still says the question is closed... So how would I know?

Answer (score -2):

The picky character of Append and different spelling of mandatory fields forced me to develop this tool:

[image]

I forgot when I last time used Append. Perhaps invest time into similar tool. You can also forget drama of field mapping.